# Windows 7 problem reporting tool analogue for Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, screenshot, screen-capture

I am very glad that Microsoft finally included a tool like "Problem reporting tool" in Windows 7 - this is a great piece of software, which I mostly use to explain other users what needs to be done to solve / figure out a certain solution for the problem that they are having.

The problem is that this tool only works on Windows 7, however at work I am using Windows XP. 
Maybe anyone knows any free similar tools for Windows XP?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There only seems to be software like "Adobe Captivate" which is able to work at least similarly to Windows 7 problem reporting tool. There seems to be no freeware alternatives available.